# Reports creation using Java

Tags: java, reporting

How can we create report in Java? Something like Crystal Reports in .net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best report engine for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238527/what-is-the-best-report-engine-for-java)

Answer (score 7):

We have [**Jasper Report**](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

> JasperReports is the world's most popular open source reporting engine. It is entirely written in Java and it is able to use data coming from any kind of data source and produce pixel-perfect documents that can be viewed, printed or exported in a variety of document formats including HTML, PDF, Excel, OpenOffice and Word.

- [Here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-tutorial) is quick tutorial

Answer (score 4):

Might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238527/what-is-the-best-report-engine-for-java), BTW...

Anyways, here's my honest (yet biased) answer copied from there:

**[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear)

- Simple and easy-to-use API of both the report engine and the [Java report viewer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/guides/Guide_Viewer_Programming.pdf).
- Can export into any major format like PDF, HTML, SVG, XLS, etc., as well as into a Java applet viewer. (See [samples](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/samples/applications/default.asp))
- Comes with a free and powerful graphical report template designer. (See [video guide](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/guides/video/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html))
- Installs as a WAR file on your application server or can be used as a library within your own application.
- Great technical support (you usually get an answer in minutes or hours rather than days or weeks)
- Charts based on [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) (so includes Stock charts).
- **Can read Crystal Reports templates.** (for a lot of customers, this is the killer feature since you don't have to re-create all your old Crystal Reports templates)
- Great and competitive pricing - effectively costing "[less than open source](http://www.inetsoftware.de/support/news/why-i-net-crystal-clear-costs-less-than-open-source)".
- Free [90-day trial](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystalclear/download_update.asp) of the server component.
- Free and fully functional [report designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer).

[full disclosure: Yes, I work for i-net software. But it's still my honest (though subjective and biased) answer to the question. ;)]

Answer (score 3):

Try [iRepor/JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/). I think is your best option as of today.

It's pretty mature, constantly updated (active), it supports StandAlone/Swing Applications, Web Applications, you can export to Excel/PDF, and integrates easily with major Appilcation Servers.

JasperReports is the Reporting Engine, and iReport is its IDE (Visual Report Editor).

Comment: I am developing web application. Can i use this use Jasper report with web application?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, it integrates pretty well with major Applications Servers: JBoss, Tomcat, Glassfish, WebSphere, WebLogic, Oracle AS...

Comment: @Chirag you can easily integrate it

Answer (score 1):

BIRT is a very popular and powerful tool. Recommended.

Comment: I am developing web application. Can i use this use BRIT with web application?

Answer (score 0):

**Jasper report** is indeed a powerfull tool, but sometimes to much work to create a report.

I would recommend to look also to **POI** and **Docx4j**. With those you can **include a template** with headers and entreprise style. You can **build the file** with simple statements but with Docx4j you can also **replace tags (templating)** in your .docx file by a element of choosing.

The docx4j(ava) documentation is available here: https://www.docx4java.org/forums/